# Undocumented bug? <lightning-record-form> fields layout change lags behind record-id change

Tags: lightning-web-components

For example, if we have 2 different record types with different page layouts.

When providing a new recordId to the *lightning-record-form* if the said record is of a different record type, the page layout change lags one step behind while the field values update correctly.

#### Example setup:

- RecordId(**A**) has PageLayout(**a**)
- RecordId(**B**) has PageLayout(**b**)
- RecordId(**B1**) has PageLayout(**b**)

#### Resulting behaviour of lightning-record-form:

steps:

1. pass RecordId(**A**) --> Displays PageLayout(**a**)  //works well 1st time
2. pass RecordId(**B**) --> Displays PageLayout(**a**)  //still "a"! ignores record type change
3. pass RecordId(**A**) --> Displays PageLayout(**b**)  //now flipped to layout "b" but late
4. pass RecordId(**B**) --> Displays PageLayout(**a**)  //again late flip out of phase
5. pass RecordId(**B1**) --> Displays PageLayout(**b**) //back to norm, but only because previous record was of the same record type

does anyone know whether it's a bug or some caching behaviour that can be worked around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I can reproduce this, I'll take time today to create a bug with salesforce.com regarding this matter.

Until then, the usual solution is to remove the entire component from the DOM and add it back after one render cycle. This causes a brief flicker, but is practically guaranteed to work.

```
showRecordForm = true
_recordId
@api set recordId(value) {
  this._recordId = value
  this.showRecordForm = false
  setTimeout(() => this.showRecordForm = true)
}
get recordId() {
  return this._recordId
}
```

...

```
<lightning-recordform if:true={showRecordForm} ...
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks Brian!